# Can a function have an x input with two y outputs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For example

```
f(4) = 3, 2
f(5) = 4
f(6) = 10
```

Please forgive me if my example is atrocious, hopefully it gets my point across.

Comment: Unless your definition of "function" is quite unusual, the answer is no, just by definition.

Comment: This is legit, but it's a so called relation, not a function. By (informal) definition functions are a special kind of relations allowing precisely one output for each input.

Comment: Thank you! I knew that if two x inputs shared a y output that it can't be a function, but I wasn't sure about the other way around.

Comment: @Thymine Actually, a function can have the same value for any number of distinct inputs. Consider for example the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$. Then we have $f(2)=4=f(-2)$.

Comment: Oh whoops. I seriously need to get some math practice in, I keep making some dumb mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: If the output of "your function" is always 2-valued, then it is a scaler to vector mapping, which can be a function depending on the mapping.

Comment: @rak: That's a bit misleading. Rather, if the output is always an *ordered* pair of (not necessarily distinct) scalars, then it is a vector-valued function. Each output is still a single "value," just not a scalar.

Comment: @cameron-buie agree. thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a good time to learn about what it means for an expression to be [well-defined](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Well-Defined.html). No doubt you are comfortable with integer arithmetic; we may define addition of fractions by
$$
\frac{x}{y}+\frac{p}{q}=\frac{xq+py}{yq}.\tag{1}
$$
This is familiar. To work correctly though, the definition in $(1)$ should not depend on which fractions we insert. For example, $\frac{2}{3}+\frac{10}{2}$ should be equivalent to, say, $\frac{-4}{-6}+\frac{5}{1}$. The definition in $(1)$ is well-defined because it *always* works and there is no ambiguity concerning the output. However, consider a different operation that may be ambiguous. Let's denote this operation by $\boxplus$ and define it as follows:
$$
\frac{x}{y}\boxplus\frac{p}{q}=\frac{xy}{pq}.\tag{2}
$$
Using $(2)$, we would have $\frac{2}{3}\boxplus\frac{10}{2}=\frac{6}{20}$, but we would also have $\frac{-4}{-6}\boxplus\frac{5}{1}=\frac{24}{5}$. Uh oh. This produces a different output than before because $\frac{6}{20}\neq\frac{24}{5}$. Thus, the operation $\boxplus$ is said to *not* be well-defined because its outputs are ambiguous based on its inputs.

How does this relate to your question specifically? Well, $f(5)=4$, and we are certain of this. There is *no ambiguity*. However, if you wrote $f(4)$, then I wouldn't know if you meant $f(4)=3$ or $f(4)=2$. That is, $f(4)$ is *ambiguous* and hence we can say that, in your case, $f(x)$ is not well-defined.

Does that help?

Comment: A nice explanation of what it means to be well defined.  (+1)

Comment: @Karl Thanks for the kind words. :)

Answer (score 1):

A function $f: A \to B$ associates to each element $a \in A$ an element $b \in B$. So for each input in $A$, there is exactly one output in $B$.

To elaborate: writing $f(4)=3,2$ does not make sense, yet writing $f(4)=(3,2)$ could make sense in a different context: 
 it could be that $B$ is a set containing ordered pairs (for instance, $B$ could be the set $\mathbb{R}^2 = \{(r,s): r,s\in \mathbb{R}\}$ of ordered pairs of real numbers). In that case, $a$ is send to an ordered pair of two numbers, but again to exactly one such pair. Furthermore, each $a \in A$ would have to be sent to such a pair.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but if I had to guess a reason why, it might be the second paragraph.

Comment: My point was to show that what the OP writes, $f(4)=3,2$ (or $(3,2)$, preferably), does make sense in a somewhat different context. But I understand that it might indeed only cause confusion?

Comment: Well, writing $f(4)=3,2$ is the same as writing $f(4)=2,3,$ semantically. Neither is an appropriate use of function notation, but both assert that the *set* of values that $f(4)$--whatever that is--may take is $\{3,2\}=\{2,3\}.$ As I [mentioned above](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452325/can-a-function-have-an-x-input-with-two-y-outputs/1452351?noredirect=1#comment2958242_1452325), the landscape is different if we use some notation to indicate an *ordered* pair, which is clearly what your second paragraph is talking about.

Comment: @user133281 I didn't downvote it either, but I am sorely tempted to. It would be a fairly odd function if its range included both integers and pairs of integers. Also saying that f(4) =3,2 is a less preferable alternative to f(4)=(3,2) is stretching things. Have you ever seen a textbook or journal article which writes pairs without () or sets without {}?

Comment: @CameronBuie: I completely agree that writing $f(4)=3,2$ makes no sense at all (yet writing $f(4)=(3,2)$ might). I have added some clarifications to the second paragraph, as I understand that the main problem is in not clearly distinguishing ordered and non-ordered pairs. If something else could be improved, please let me know.